# Facebook Api Call Limit Exceeding too soon

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, lumen

I'm trying to call facebook api for scraping my page again and again. 
But when ever i try it once its limit reach very soon. I call api 2 or 3 times and its reaches to limit. My code for calling API is

```
$router->get('/', ["as" => "home", function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request,\Facebook\Facebook $fb) use ($colors) {
    if ($request->getHttpHost() === 'localhost') {
        $limit = count($colors) - 1;
        try {
            $response = $fb->post('/?scrape=true&id=http://color1.tk/');
            $response->getGraphNode();
        }catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $exception){
            Log::addDebug($exception->getMessage());
        }
        return view('index')->with("color", $colors[rand(0,$limit)]);
    }else{
        return "This action is not allowed";
    }
}]);
```

and on facebook app stats page i see this after refreshing page 2 or 3 times 
[Facebook api limit reaching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXBC1.png)

Comment: why would you scrape your page again and again? and are you using an access token for this?

Comment: @luschn yes i am using access token for this .... Application access token. Scrape to update some info that is requirement of my project :)

Comment: yeah, but what for exactly do you want to scrape stuff again and again? maybe you are doing something you are not supposed to do, that´s why i am asking, and that´s why you may hit limits soon.

Comment: i got it man thanks alot